# Python Numpy add hspace between 3D plot and 2D plot with shared axes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Attached is an image showing the current plot. I am setting `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` for the 2D plots to share a common x-axis. I would like to add space between the 3D and 2d plots but am not quite sure how to accomplish this as hspace is set to 0.

```
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
for ax in [px_t, py_t, pz_t]:
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your code to give some context?  Ideally - something that we can cut and paste and just run, with a bit of sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it's best to use two separate `GridSpec` instances.  That way you can have two separate `hspace` parameters.  Alternatively, you can manually place the top axes.

As an example of the first option:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
gs1 = plt.GridSpec(2, 1, hspace=0.2)
gs2 = plt.GridSpec(8, 1, hspace=0)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0], projection='3d')
ax1.plot(range(10), range(10), range(10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs2[4])
lower_axes = [ax]
for i in range(4, 8):
    if i > 4:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs2[i], sharex=lower_axes[0])
    ax.plot(range(10))
    ax.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5, prune='both')
    lower_axes.append(ax)

for ax in lower_axes:
    ax.label_outer()

plt.show()
```

[image]